# How to disable Guest Access from Terminal in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, bash, terminal

I'm trying to disable Guest Account from terminal.

I need the same effect like disabling *System Preferences → Accounts → Guest Account → Allow guests to connect to shared folders*.

I think Guest Access is disabled by default on Lion, So I need it for 10.5, and 10.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On OS X Lion, the preference is internally realized as two separate options:

In `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.AppleFileServer`, it's the `guestAccess` flag, and in `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server.plist`, it's the `AllowGuestAccess` flag.

To change these, execute the following with `root` permissions:

```
defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.AppleFileServer guestAccess -bool NO
defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server AllowGuestAccess -bool NO
```

Not sure if these are the same in previous versions of OS X. Use `defaults read <path>` to find out if these options exist on your system.

You might need to relaunch the sharing service for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks it works good for me. It does disable Guest Account if you use only first line for AppleFileServer. Do you have idea what is SMB guest access seperately?Because it shows after first line, that user is disabled.Thanks!